# Is there a problem with Ta'anit Baha"b coinciding with Pesach Sheni?

Tags: fast-days, pesach-sheni

If the 1st day of Pesach were to occur on Sunday, I noticed that the fast of Baha"b (Some have a custom to fast on the 1st Monday, 1st Thursday and 2nd Monday following Rosh Hodesh Iyyar) would occur on the following dates:

- Monday 7 Iyyar
- Thursday 10 Iyyar
- Monday 14 Iyyar which is Pesach Sheni

Some people have the custom of [reciting selichot](http://5tjt.com/the-practice-of-bahab/) on Ta'anit Behab. However, Pesach Sheni is a joyous holiday, in some sense. It was the day that people who were *tameh* (ritually impure) on Pesach and couldn't make the Pesach sacrifice, a 2nd chance to eat that sacrifice on 14 Iyar. Today, some have the custom to omit Tachanun on Pesach Sheni, a custom that is often done on holidays.

So there seems to be a contradiction between the joy of Pesach Sheni and the fasting on Beha"b. Since Pesach Sheni was a Biblical holiday, and Beha"b is a minhag, if the 2nd Monday of Beha"b is on Pesach Sheni, is fasting cancelled or postponed?

Comment: This question is a bit anachoristic, as Bahab is an Ashkenazi custom, but celebrating Pesach Sheni post-Temple is not an Ashkenazi custom. (Nowadays with people mixing up Minhagim you might get communities who have this issue, but it's a new question.)

Comment: @DoubleAA Chaba"d and a number of other Ashkenazim celebrate Pesach Sheni in some way - fewer than those that observe BAH"B, I would think.

Comment: I didn't say no Ashkenazim celebrate it. I said it's not an Ashkenazi custom. Some Ashkenazim it seems recently decided they were going to import other practices from elsewhere (especially if it gets them out of saying Tachanun). Nu nu. That's how you end up with new weird contradictions like this: cherry-picking Minhagim.

Comment: BHB is not mentioned in S.A.? @DoubleAA

Comment: @kouty It is in OC 492. See the Tur נוהגים באשכנז ובצרפת להתענות שני וחמישי ושני אחר הפסח והחג.

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://www.chareidi.org/archives5762/achrei/obahab.htm) states:

> If one of the actual days of BaHaB falls out on Pesach Sheni, the
>   minhag is not to fast or to say Selichos. The fast can be made up on
>   the following Thursday or Monday (Mahrasham 6,33; Luach Eretz
>   Yisroel). As on other yomim tovim, eulogies are not said. Therefore
>   one should not plan a hakomas matzeivoh for Pesach Sheni, since
>   eulogies generally accompany this ceremony (Response Minchas Yitzchok
>   3,53).

Comment: This seems to not be universally accepted http://revach.net/tefila/article.php?id=2246 Indeed no Rishonim mention this seemingly since it was obvious that Pesach Sheni is not relevant nowadays

Comment: Pesach Sheni is not a festival. for people which make pessach rishon in time of BHMK it probabily was nothing. I heard in name of gedolim (חז"א) to say tachanun.

Comment: As noted this case is not discussed in classical halachic literature, but FWIW a parallel case is discussed (second monday of Bahab for rain on Rosh Chodesh Kislev) and the conclusion is to fast on the following Thursday instead.