May Jews fast on Yom Ha’atzmut or Yom Yerushayalim
According to the interpretation of Halacha by religious Zionist rabbis who say that Jews should recite Hallel on Yom Yerushalayim and Yom Ha’atzmut, may Jews fast on Yom Ha’atzmut or Yom Yerushayalim? Or no, according to the opinion  Hallel should be recited, is fasting prohibited as well?

This used to be very relevant (to the incredibly small intersection of those who fast Behab and those who observe Yom Haatzmaut) when Yom Haatzmaut could fall on Monday of Bahab, but since ~2004 (?) it gets pushed off to Tuesday.

A somewhat parallel case of a modern made-up holiday coinciding with a fast day is  pesach-sheni/bahab https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/71214/759

Who would want to fast on a holiday?

@DoubleAA Unless you include those who mark 5 Iyyar irrespective of the Rabbinate’s decision on when to celebrate Yom HaAtzmaut. I believe that in the main YU Beis Hamedrash thia year they said both Selichot and Hallel on Monday 5 Iyyar.

@mbloch Yahrtzeit, wedding, behab, bad dream, etc.
